# Trigger Cloud Function with Eventarc and then extract BigQuery table as csv files

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

Problem:

> Whenever new data are inserted, extract BigQuery tables as csv files and
> store them in Cloud Storage.

My plan:
Set up an Eventarc trigger based on Event method
`google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.InsertJob` for Cloud Function to identify when new data are inserted into BigQuery.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import functions_framework


client = bigquery.Client()
bucket_name = "bucket"
project = "astute-coda-410816"
dataset_id = "dataset"


def move_data(table):
    #extract BigQuery table
    destination_uri = f"gs://{bucket_name}/{table}/{table}-*.csv"
    dataset_ref = bigquery.DatasetReference(project,dataset_id)
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table(f"{table}")
    job_config = bigquery.job.ExtractJobConfig(print_header=False)
    client.extract_table(table_ref, destination_uri, location="US",job_config=job_config)
    print(f"Exported {project}:{dataset_id}.{table} to {destination_uri}")


@functions_framework.cloud_event
def transfer(cloudevent):
    payload = cloudevent.data.get("protoPayload")
    status = payload.get("status")
    if not status: #if status is empty, the insert job is successful and tables should be extracted to Cloud Storage
        move_data("table_1")
        move_data("table_2")
        move_data("table_3")
```

My questions are:

- Anything else I should do to improve my code?
- Is there a way to run in parallel the data transfer for all 3 tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good.

## optional type annotation

This would be a better signature:

```
def move_data(table: str) -> None:
```

It turns out we're really passing in a table name,
rather than some fancy table object.
I didn't learn that detail until I got down to the calling code.
This line mislead me:

```
    ... = dataset_ref.table(f"{table}")
```

I have no idea why you're calling `str(table)`, given
that `table` should *already* be a `str`.

In the interest of naming consistency, consider calling
it just `bucket` rather than `bucket_name`.

nit: Running [$ black -S *.py](https://pypi.org/project/black)
on this wouldn't hurt, to tidy up the spacing a bit.

## meaningful identifier

Thank you for this helpful comment, I appreciate it.

```
    if not status:  # if status is empty, the insert job is successful and tables should be extracted to Cloud Storage
```

I imagine Google's docs refer to the return value as a `status`.

Here, it might be more helpful to name it `errors`,
and then there would be no need for that comment.

Let's talk about the missing `else:` clause.
If there *are* errors, wouldn't you like for a
[logger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html)
to report the details?

## multiprocessing

> a way to run in parallel the data transfer for all 3 tables?

```
import multiprocessing
    ...
    tables = [f"table_{i}" for i in range(1, 4)]

    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        pool.map(move_data, tables)
```

Consider using one of the variant mappers, such as
[imap_unordered()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap_unordered),
which grant greater latitude to the scheduler
by relaxing the ordering constraints.

---

This code achieves its design goals.

I would be willing to delegate or accept
maintenance tasks on it.

Comment: You're correct, table is already a string. For the f"{table}" line, it was originally f"{table}_i" with i being part of for i in range(len(table_list)). I later changed this but forgot to remove the f string